# Can you use the Firefox @-moz-document directive in a SASS file?

Tags: css, firefox, sass, mindscape

So you can use the following CSS to override a style in Firefox only:

```
button.needs-overridden-in-firefox {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 16px;

}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* firefox line-height behaves differently, compensate with padding-top  */
    button.needs-overridden-in-firefox {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

...but can this be written as a style in a SASS file? I have tried the following and got a compiler error with mindscape web workbench's compiler.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    button.needs-overridden-in-firefox {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try upgrading your version of Sass (I'm using an edge/beta version and do not get an error).

Comment: I second what @cimmanon says ... and here is an example of it working fine on Sassmeister: [**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7456210)

Comment: Thank you both, updating to the latest mindscape webworkbench seems to compile this.

Comment: umm, it does not throw an error in the preprocessor, but it does not work in a newer Firefox anymore, does it? I am using FF 48.